# Passing in One or More "sets" of Parameters to One function?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to streamline and make some code more reusable. I have a function that would need to be able to take 1 or more "sets" of parameters.

```
function myFunc(options, value) {
    col[options] = value;
    //goal is to be able to pass in one or more "sets" of col[options] = value;
}
```

Here I would be passing in two "sets" of parameters and I would want it to look like this:

```
function myFunc(options, value) {
    col[year] = 3016;
    col[type] = fixed;
    //passing in two sets for example, but could be 1 or more
}
```

I'm feel like I may be thinking about this wrong. Is this possible?

Comment: Why not just pass `col`? `function myFunc (col) {}` then call it as `myFunc({year:3016,type:fixed})`

Comment: Exactly just pass the whole object as param